# Parallel.run syntax

Tags: javascript, dart

I just watched [this introduction from the Dart Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiXiI2Atexc). During the talk, this code was put up:

```
=> new List.generate(100, (y) => renderLine(y));
```

I'm pretty sure I understand that line. The arrow function is new to me but okay - it looks a little coffee-esque. The point though, was changing this function to run in parallel which was done like this:

```
=> Parallel.run(new List.generate(100, (y) => () => renderLine(y)));
```

Can someone explain the syntax of `(y) => () => renderLine(y)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(y) => () => renderLine(y)` is a function that returns a function. If you write it without the `=>` shorthand, it is the same as:

```dart
(y) {
  return () {
    return renderLine(y);
  };
}
```

This means that the `List.generate` calls this function 100 times, with different values for `y`. Each call returns a function that will call `renderLine` with a different value.

This generates a list of *functions* (each taking zero arguments). 
That list is the argument to `Parallel.run`.

So, the code is just using a quick in-line way to create a list, but it is equivalent to:

```dart
var tempList = [];
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) tempList.add(() => renderLine(y));
Parallel.run(tempList);
```

The `Parallel.run` function expects a list of functions, and will run the functions in parallel, so you get 100 calls to `renderLine` executed in parallel, each with a different argument.

Comment: But how does this do anything for `Parallel.run`?

Answer (score 0):

`(y) => () => renderLine()` is a function which is passed as second parameter to `Parallel.run()` and this function takes one argument and returns a function which doesn't take any argument.

I don't know why it is done this way.

`(x, y) => x + y;` is just a shorthand for `(x, y) { return x + y; }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (haven't watched the video) that the `Parallel.run()` function receives a list (or iterable) of no-arg functions to run in parallel.  The `List.generate()` constructor takes an `int` (length) and a function (which takes one `int` as an argument) and generates that many items by calling the function for each `int` in the range `0 .. n-1`.  So the code `new List.generate(100, (y) => renderLine(y))` generates a `List` of 100 items, each of which is the result of calling `renderLine()` on each index (that is, `renderLine(0), renderLine(1), ... , renderLine(99)`).

The code `new List.generate(100, (y) => () => renderLine(y))` returns a list of 100 items, aech of which is a function which takes no argumens, and which when called, calls `renderLine()` with its index in the list.  That is, the list is: `() => renderLine(0), () => renderLine(1), () => renderLine(2), ..., () => renderLine(99)`.

I'm guessing `Parallel.run()` then runs all those functions in parallel, maybe aggregating the results in a list and returning it?  If so, then the code `Parallel.run(new List.generate(100, (y) => () => renderLine(y)))` does something similar to `new List.generate(100, (y) => () => renderLine(y))`, except in parallel rather than sequentially.